# How to access contents of directory

Tags: ios4

I have a directory which contain multiple files like .jpg,.txt & all other.
I want to get the path for each file programetically & store it in an array.
I have done it through using contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error: method of NSFileManager but it gives me the object stored on the directory path.
i Want to get the content path of directory path that i provide.
Is this possible?? IF so how?
Any kind of suggestions are appreciable.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand "it gives me the object stored on the directory path".

Comment: i mean in the array i get file objects but not the path for those objects .i want to display these objects in a tableview !

Answer (score 0):

`- (NSArray *)contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:(NSString *)path error:(NSError **)error` is the correct method to use. From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html), it returns:

> An array of NSString objects
>   identifying the directories and files
>   (including symbolic links) contained
>   in path. Returns an empty array if the
>   directory exists but has no contents.
>   Returns nil if the directory specified
>   at path does not exist or there is
>   some other error accessing it.